# How to NOT vertically center text in a <button> element?

Tags: html, css

How would you go about positioning the text in this `<button>` in the upper left or bottom right (or whatever)? I can't figure out what's causing it to vertically align the way it is, or how to override it.

```
<button>
    <time>Foo</time>
    <br />
    <span>Bar</span>
</button>

button {
    display: block;
    width: 124px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    text-align: left;
    background: #EEE;
}
```

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hNs7q/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Surround the text in a div, set a class on the div. Use custom css on that div to move it where ever you want.

```
<button>
    <div class="move">
        <time>Foo</time>
    <br />
    <span>Bar</span>
     </div>
</button>

button {
display: block;
width: 124px;
height: 200px;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
border-radius: 0;
text-align: left;
background: #EEE;
}

.move{
    padding-top:50px;   
}
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/gzTax/

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your inner elements in a div and set the position on the button to relative, and the position on the div to absolute like this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hNs7q/6/)**:

```
<button>
    <div>
        <time>Foo</time>
        <br /> <span>Bar</span>
    </div>
</button>
button {
    display: block;
    width: 124px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    text-align: left;
    background: #EEE;
    position:relative;
}
div {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a solution that lets you change the alignment without any additional markup, you can try playing around with the padding. For example, reduce the `height` and increase the `padding-top` value.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/hNs7q/14/